# Subtleties in the calculation of limits associated with adherent points

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Just want to check if I understand formal definitions of limits and continuity correctly (i.e. everything that I wrote is correct) 
 
 
Suppose we have a function $f: (0, +\infty) \rightarrow R$ , $\;$ $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}$

I compute three limits at  $0$. (This is about my understanding of two-sided and one-sided limits)

I'm learning from Tao book. There he uses an improved limit definition:
$$\lim_{x \to x_0, \; x \in E} f(x)$$ where $E$ can be any subset of $X$ (not only the usual $X -x_0$), $x_0$ should be an adherent of $E$ for that matter, the same remains as in the usual definition of a limit)

Before I start I'd like to make a notice of how I work with limits

1. Fix some subset E of original domain X
2. Fix some point in which i would like to calculate a limit
3. Check whether or not this point is an adherent point of E.
4. If it's not an adherent point then the limit is not defined. (I.e. there is no such notion - we can't say that this means that function diverges in this point for example.)
5. If it is an adherent point then we can talk about its convergence or divergence (it will be one and exactly one of those)

---

Now we compute two sided-limit. I claim that it equals to $+ \infty$
$$\lim_{x \to 0, \; x \in X} \; \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} = + \infty$$ For that let's take an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ and $${\delta = \frac {1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon ^ 2}}}$$ this means that $$\sqrt {\frac{1}{\delta}} \geq \varepsilon$$
and any $x$ from $(0, +\infty)$, such that $|x| \leq \delta$. (Unwrapping formal definition here)

Now for that x we have to show that $|f(x)| \geq \varepsilon$

But since $x$ is in $(0, +\infty)$ it is positive, so we have $\frac {1}{x} > \frac {1}{\delta}$ and $|f(x)| = f(x)$ so in the end we have  $$|f(x)| = \sqrt{\frac {1}{x}} > \sqrt{\frac{1}{ \delta}} \geq \varepsilon$$

So, indeed 
$$\lim_{x \to 0, \; x \in X} \; \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} = + \infty$$

Next we take right-sided limit
$$\lim_{x \to 0, \; x \in X  \cap (0, + \infty)} \; \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} $$

The intersection $X  \cap (0, + \infty) = (0, + \infty)$ is in fact equal to $X$, so this limit is the same as previous one, thus we have $$\lim_{x \to 0, \; x \in X  \cap (0, + \infty)} \; \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} = +\infty$$

Finally let's take left sided limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0, \; x \in X  \cap (- \infty, 0)} \; \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} $$

The intersection here $(0, + \infty)  \cap (- \infty, 0)$ is, in fact, equal to the empty set and no point can be an adherent point of the empty set (because of vacuous implications) So this limit is ill-defined.

---

If I computed everything right then this is quite interesting because this shows some subtleties in using one-sided limit theorem. (Two sided limit exists while one of one-sided is not defined)

---

In the same passion it seems to me that the function 
$$f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{0,} &\quad\text{x}\le0\\
       \text{1,} &\quad\text{x}\ge1 \\
     \end{cases}$$ is continuous! (Though it does not pass pen draw test)

(For a function to be continuous means to be continuous in every point of its domain, right?)

Also, is the notion of continuity defined only for a domain of a function? (In the very same way as the notion of limit is defined only for an adherent point of a set) I.e. it makes no sence to ask or say whether my function is continuous or discontinous in, say, $x = 1/2$?)

Let's check for example it's continuity in zero.

For any $\varepsilon$ we take $\delta = 1/2$.
Now for any x from its domain, which also satisfies $|x| < 1/2$ we have $f(x) = 0$ obviously, so that $|f(x)-0| = 0 < \epsilon$.

Once again here right-sided limit is not defined.